# Typescript overload/edit given types by 3rd library component in React.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

typescript beginner here.

I am trying to convert my existing react project to use typescript.
Now I changed my file to tsx, and got bunch of errors most I could fix.
But I am stuck with 1 type I cannot find answers to online, To overload 3rd library types with my own.

For example, I am using ant design for my components which brings its own types inside:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Select, Form } from 'antd';
import { AdvancedSelectPROPS, selectOptionItem } from '../types';
const FormItem = Form.Item;
const Option = Select.Option;

const SelectElement = React.memo(function InputElement(props: AdvancedSelectPROPS) {
    const { status, hasfeed, error, label, formItemStyle, disabled, forwhom, value, options = [], ...otherProps } = props;

    return (
        <FormItem
            validateStatus={disabled ? (status === 'error' ? 'error' : 'warning') : status === 'error' ? 'error' : ''}
            className="addLabel"
            hasFeedback={hasfeed === 'true'}
            help={status === 'error' ? error : ''}
            style={formItemStyle}
            label={label}
        >
            <Select {...otherProps} disabled={disabled} value={!value ? [] : value} forwhom={forwhom}> 
              // I have added new prop "forwhom" which is not provided by the types of ant design
                {options.map((item: selectOptionItem, index) => {
                    return (
                        <Option value={item.value} key={item.name + index}>
                            {item.name || item.Name}
                        </Option>
                    );
                })}
            </Select>
        </FormItem>
    );
});

export default SelectElement;
```

I have added new prop "forwhom" which is not provided by the types of ant design.
Now I would like to add new props and their types to the built in types, how is something like that is done?

I tried

```
declare namespace JSX {
  interface Select {
        forwhom: string | number
    }
}
```

or

```
declare namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicAttributes {
        forwhom: string | number
    }
    interface IntrinsicClassAttributes {
        forwhom: string | number
    }
}
```

But it didnt work.

Error:

```
Property 'forwhom' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Select<any>> & Pick<Pick<Readonly<SelectProps<any>> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>, "disabled" | "style" | "prefixCls" | ... 50 more ... | "loading"> & Pick<...> & Pick<...>, "disabled" | ... 51 more ... | "loading"> & Partial<...> & Partial<...>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
// types/antd.ts
declare module "antd/lib/select" {
  export interface SelectProps {
    forwhom: string | number;
  }
}

export {}; // you only need this line if "--isolatedModules" is provided to tsc
```

After that you need to import both, your custom typing (here `./types/antd.ts`) and the `Select` from `antd`:

```
import "./types/antd";
import { Select } from "antd";

// ...

<Select forwhom={1} /> // works
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-https-8pln2)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried adding the code you sent, but it didnt change nothing.

Comment: @Kiper i added a codesandbox link in my answer. There it's also working fine. Maybe you have a different `antd` version (`v 3.25.1`)?

Comment: Hi thank you for making it. Ill try again when I'll be back at work.